# Benefits of Abstract methods over Method Overriding

Tags: java

Scenarios where we can go for abstract class and where we can go for method overriding.
Let me explain.
I have  a class A.

```
abstract class A {
    abstract public void display();
}
```

and In usual case I can extend this class as

```
class B extends A {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("This is a bike");
    }
}
```

The same this I could do by using method overriding feature even if the method of the class A has something.

So my question is, when should I go for abstract class when the same feature i can achieve by method overriding.

Comment: Isn't the main perk of using abstract classes that you can't instantiate them (like interfaces) but can provide a base constructor and extend other classes (like classes)?

Comment: I don't understand your question: If you have an abstract class with an abstract method, you will have to override it in the subclass.

Comment: you already have method overriding here because you override display method

Answer (score 1):

The main point of an abstract class/method is to provide a base type for polymorphic usage. In other words, you have some base type A that others will extend to provide some operation. You do not care about the exact implementation, but you to want that operation to be available.

An often-cited example is a Shape class:

```
abstract class Shape {
    public abstract void draw();
}
class Circle extends Shape {
    int radius;
    // Constructors, etc.
    @Override 
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Circle of radius " + radius);
    }
}
class Square extends Shape {
    int side;
    // Constructors, etc.
    @Override 
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Square of side " + radius);
    }
}
```

Class Shape is a way of referring to any shape. You know that there cannot be instances of class Shape, but you can still have a `Shape[]` or a `List<Shape>`. That way, you can use it like this:

```
void drawAll(Iterable<? extends Shape> shapes) {
    for (final Shape s : shapes)
        s.draw();
}
```

If you didn't have an abstract base class Shape, you would not be able to write this method; you would have to write one for a list of Circle objects and another one for a list of Square objects - and even that solution would still not allow you to do this:

```
List<Shape> ls = Arrays.asList(new Circle(7), new Square(5));
drawAll(ls);
```

Comment: This is not entirely right. All of this would be possible, even if `Shape` and its `draw()` method were not abstract. The main benefit is that you force each sub-class of `Shape` to either override `draw()` or be abstract itself. You cannot (easily) enforce the override of existing methode.

Comment: @Turing85 indeed... my point was the advantage of having Shape over _not_ having it (and thus just having a series of "unrelated" classes with a draw method). The "closest thing" to `abstract` without actually using the keyword would be to have `Shape.draw()` throw an exception, so any useful implementation would have to override it.

Comment: You cannot declare the method `draw` without body; you need to declare it as abstract: `public abstract void draw();`.

Comment: @MCEmperor you can declare it with an empty body or - as Javier said - with only a `throw ...` statement in its body. But that is the point of the whole discussion: then you cannot enforce overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class is a class that has at least one abstract method. That is a method that is not implemented in this class but has to be implemented by derived classes.

Abstract classes should be used to represent abstract concepts. You cannot create objects from abstract classes, they are only used to derive concrete classes from them.

Actually, my opinion is that abstract classes don't make sense in most cases. You should use interfaces instead.

Comment: "An abstract class is a class that has at least one abstract method. That is a method that is not implemented in this class but has to be implemented by derived classes." This is not correct. In C++ you would be right, but [in Java you can declare a class abstract, even if it has no abstract methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

Comment: @Turing85: You can, yes, but would you?

Comment: [Of course](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html).

Comment: Abstract classes are helpful with the `protected` keyword, so that each extension of the class has a unique instance of that variable.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: Abstract methods  eoncorporate overriding. In this sense, your question is somehwat ill-formulated.

Now to the bear in the room: In your example, you gave example classes `A` and `B`:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract public void display();
}

class B extend A {
    @Override
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("This is a bike");
    }
}
```

I added the `@Override` annotation to furhter enforce the notion that abstraction uses overriding. If `display()` in `A` would not be `absatract`, you would not have any (easy) possibility to enforce that each sub-class of `A` has a methode `display()`. You could of course implement `display()` within `A`.

In some cases, though, this might not be possible since you do not have enough information to write the method in question. Take for example the `get(int index)` method of some list. The implementation of the getter depends heavily on the list implementation (accessing the 100th element of an `ArrayList` works fundamentally different than accessing the 100th element of a `LinkedList`). But yon know for sure that each list should always have this method. So you make this method abstract<sup>1</sup>.

To sum up: In a perfect world, where every programmer writes and reads docs, you probably would not need abstract methods. But we are all humans (i.e. we do not read every line of documentation and we make mistakes/forget things) and therefore it is good to have some protection against this mistakes. Furthermore, it is counter-intuitive to have empty methods and expect users to overwrite them for your program/library to work.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Sidenote: In actuality `List` is an interface, not a class. I used this example only for demonstration purpose.</sub>